# Manipulating data from a CVS file in PHP

Tags: php, macos, fgets

okay i'm a bit stuck just now.

As a task i have been given, i have to make a "star processor" from data coming out of a cvs file here is my cvs file

```
    Number,Character,Order

      5,*,0
      4,*,1
      3,*,2
      2,*,3
      1,*,4
      2,*,5
      3,*,6
      4,*,7
      5,-,8
```

What i'm trying to output -

```
    *****
    ****
    ***
    **
    *
    **
    ***
    ****
    -----
```

Hopefully you get the idea

Here is what i have just now -

```
    $starsFile = fopen("stars.csv", "r");


    while (!feof($starsFile)) {
        print_r (fgetcsv($starsFile, ","));
      }


    fclose($starsFile);
```

this basically just returns the CSV data in arrays which is cool!

What i'm stuck on is figuring out how to access the array that 'fgetcsv' creates? is there another data structure that i can use? and help or pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to do additional processing in your while loop. Look at the manual for fgetcsv and see if that helps. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Read [example #6](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for an explanation of how to access data in arrays

Comment: Thanks alot for the help really do appreciate it! :DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (($starsFile = fopen("stars.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($starsFile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // no. of times the symbol needs to be displayed
        $num_symbol_display = (int)$data[0];
        // the symbol to be displayed
        $symbol = $data[1];

        // logic to display the symbol
        for ($i=1; $i<=$num_symbol_display; $i++){
            echo $symbol;
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
    fclose($starsFile);
}
```

From the original question it is not clear what the 3rd field is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
$starsFile = fopen("stars.csv", "r");

while (!feof($starsFile)) {
    $stars = fgetcsv($starsFile, ",");
    print str_repeat($stars[1], intval($stars[0]))."\n";
}

fclose($starsFile);
```

Comment: Sure, you can extend this code to use the third field `Order`. But generally you should use $var = fgetcsv(... to get array of values on each string.